# Syntax Error while trying to create database using gpx2spatialite_create_db

Tags: python-2.7, windows-installer, home-directory

I'm trying to use gpx2spatialite but I'm stumped with setting the path needed..I have already installed the module and I see the gpx2spatialite files in my python scripts and site-packages folder. The instructions say

[  Make sure that $HOME/.local/bin is available in your PATH environment variable. Otherwise the gpx2spatialite executable will not be found when you run it from the shell:

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin  ] from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gpx2spatialite

What is PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin in windows 8?

I already have [  C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;  ] in my environment path.

I found this: [  The Windows equivalent of HOME is the user-specific application data directory .. C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming  ] from htttp://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html so I substituted and typed in [  C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming.local\bin  ] in my environment path.

Still, when I tried to follow the instructions for creating a spatial database for GPX given in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/how-to-build-a-geographic-database-of-gps-logs, I get an invalid syntax error which I feel is not a syntax error at all but might actually be due to a missing path.

I really hope somebody can help me out on this..
*By the way, I'm a newbie here and I wanted to tag this question under gpx2spatialite. Seems I won't be able to do so yet..

Answer (score 0):

Issue was discussed on https://github.com/ptrv/gpx2spatialite/issues/20

Windows installation instructions were given on https://github.com/ptrv/gpx2spatialite/tree/one-script#windows:

> Download python 2.7 32bit for windows
>
> Install pip.
>
> Install gpxpy with pip install gpxpy
>
> Download mod_spatialte and extract all dlls to C:\Python27\Scripts
>
> Download sqlite3.dll (something like 'sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3080704.zip') and overwrite sqlite3.dll in C:\Python27\Scripts\DLLs with the downloaded version (This ensures that sqlite3.dll is capable of loading extensions)
>
> Install gpx2spatialite with pip install gpx2spatialite